# How to install .NET 4.5 SDK?

Tags: installation, .net-framework, sdk

I have a problem installing .NET 4.5 SDK.

When I run the sdksetup.exe (Windows SDK setup, which also includes the .NET 4.5 SDK), the wizard successfully gets to the point of choosing the components to install. I only need .NET 4.5 SDK, hence I select the appropriate checkbox and turn others off:

[image: download error]

In the log files I can see the errors while trying to download the MSI from the web:

```
[19BC:0690][2013-07-12T17:11:44]: package_Microsoft_.NET_Framework_4.5_Tools
[19BC:0690][2013-07-12T17:11:44]: package_Microsoft_.NET_Framework_4.5_Tools to http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/1/3/F1300C9C-A120-4341-90DF-8A52509B23AC/standalonesdk/Installers/sdk_tools4.msi
[19BC:0690][2013-07-12T17:11:44]: Acquiring package: package_Microsoft_.NET_Framework_4.5_Tools, payload: package_Microsoft_.NET_Framework_4.5_Tools, download from: http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/1/3/F1300C9C-A120-4341-90DF-8A52509B23AC/standalonesdk/Installers/sdk_tools4.msi
[19BC:0690][2013-07-12T17:11:44]: Error 0x80070002: Failed to send request to URL: http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/1/3/F1300C9C-A120-4341-90DF-8A52509B23AC/standalonesdk/Installers/sdk_tools4.msi
[19BC:0690][2013-07-12T17:11:44]: Error 0x80070002: Failed to connect to URL: http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/1/3/F1300C9C-A120-4341-90DF-8A52509B23AC/standalonesdk/Installers/sdk_tools4.msi
[19BC:0690][2013-07-12T17:11:44]: Error 0x80070002: Failed to get size and time for URL: http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/1/3/F1300C9C-A120-4341-90DF-8A52509B23AC/standalonesdk/Installers/sdk_tools4.msi
[19BC:0690][2013-07-12T17:11:44]: Error 0x80070002: Failed attempt to download URL: 'http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/1/3/F1300C9C-A120-4341-90DF-8A52509B23AC/standalonesdk/Installers/sdk_tools4.msi' to: 'C:\Users\ys\AppData\Local\Temp\{a3717ca4-b44e-422d-8268-ee4dabb332fd}\package_Microsoft_.NET_Framework_4.5_Tools'
```

I've also tried to download the MSI package manually, but failed. 
I found out another machine which has that SDK installed, and copied the mentioned MSI file from the Windows Installer cache, but the SDK setup complains the package is invalid...

Anyone has any ideas? I suppose downloading the valid sdk_tools4.msi and satellite .cab file will solve the problem, but where can I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, as it often happens, once I posted this question, I managed to solve the problem.

So, here's the descriptino for those who face with the problem in future.

First of all, I failed to download the .NET 4.5 SDK from the internet, and I had to copy the necessary files from the machine, which has it installed. I don't know why it didn't work the first time, though. So, I copied the following files:

- sdk_tools4.msi
- sdk_tools4.cab
- NetFx45_DTP.msi
- NetFx45_DTP.cab

The installation process then looked like this:

- Run `sdksetup.exe`
- Choose only `.NET 4.5 SDK setup` checkbox
- It attempts to download the package, fails and prompts for the local path. Point it to the local copy of sdk_tools4.msi (I suppose it expects the `cab` file in the same directory)
- Repeat the previous step for `NetFx45_DTP.msi`

Afterwards, the installation went smoothly and installed the .NET 4.5 SDK successfully.

NOTE: if you don't have a machine where .NET 4.5 SDK is already installed, it might be a show stopper for you.